# Why do I get an SqlClientPermission exception?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have built a C# WinForms application which accesses a SQL Server 2008 for data manipulation.

The application works fine on the machine that was developed on. However when I copy the EXEs and move it to another computer (Windows XP), I got the following error during the login to the system (in other words, when i access the database).

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed
```

Here's my connection string:

```
Data Source=vmsql;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=ChequeBookInventory
```

[Stack trace is given in a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGiVo.jpg)

Any idea how to fix this issue?!

Comment: Was there anything specific in the error message or is that all you were given? Posting the StackTrace could be helpful so you can see the methods it took before the error occured.

Comment: Check .NET runtime version on the target machine. I had a similar error when executed my .NET 2 app in .NET 1...

Comment: Dmitry - I tried installing the .NET 3.5 SP1 framework.. still no luck :-(

Comment: Jamie, the screen shot of the stack trace is added to the question :).. Thanks

Comment: @Jamie-keeling The screen shot is added now... Please take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well It was a combination of things that did the trick...

1. Setup code level access... I had allow full trust on machine level that network share URL through .NET Fx configuration (Whc i had to install seperately)
2. Install .NET latest version.. (I stuck to 3.5 ;-] )

Thanks for all the help guys :-)!!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the program is not executed with full trust. Either because the computer is configured like this or you are running it from a network share...
Some more info can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e91bfb53-5148-4122-894c-56dc0d0b6a29/).

Comment: tried out the Caspol.exe command... still no luck... very critical issue.

Comment: I was able to execute the following command still no luck though...
caspol -m -cg LocalIntranet_Zone -allcode FullTrust

Comment: Yeap... copied it locally to the XP machine still no luck :(.. My neck is on the line here (Like always)

Comment: Did you try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/1505d7e6-59dc-4997-b707-9e9736a1f978/) solution?

Comment: Tried the Config tool change.. still no luck!

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth 

and added the security exception code piece, still no luck...

`code`[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted)]
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted)]
    [AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted)] `code`

Answer (score 0):

Grant the executing user rights to the database.

Comment: Are both machines part of a domain?

Comment: yeah! and i have given full access just to make sure it's working :)... still no luck!

Answer (score -2):

If you want to connect to SQL Server remotely, and don't want use the username and password but Windows Authentication, that's just one way - "AD" ,I think AD might cause more problems (but AD is more secure), and I am **really sorry** about that my answer is not correct, I found some references about that issue,I think it might be help.

[1.How to troubleshoot the "Cannot generate SSPI context" error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811889/en-us)

[2.“Cannot Generate SSPI Context” error message, more comments for SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/15/481297.aspx)

[3.“Cannot generate SSPI context” error message, when connect to local SQL Server outside domain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/19/482782.aspx)

[4.Service Principal Names (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[5."Access Denied" error message when you try to access remote resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822707/en-us)

### that's bad answer bellow:

If you use `"Integrated Security=SSPI"`, that means you can't connect to SQL Server remotely.

if you want to connect remotely, please use `"User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"` instead of `"Integrated Security=SSPI"`.

(Of course your SQL Server must accept "remote connection")[connection string for connecting to data sources](http://www.vkinfotek.com/connectionstring.html)

Comment: That's not true. You CAN connect to MS SQL Server remotely using `"Integrated Security=SSPI"`